# Drupal 7 + jQuery, how to get jQuery to interact only with the active node (via nid) and not every node in the list

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, view

I've been searching for a very long time without any luck within the subject, please point me in the right direction if I have been missing an older thread.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

Having a regular view of multiple nodes and by pressing a button (or whatever) within a node make jQuery interact with this specific node in any way. Ex. make a hidden div appear.

**The problems I'm facing** are for starters that I'm still finding it hard to work with jQuery together with D7. I've been using jQ for a very long time before but when using it together with D7 I'm facing major problems.

**And the biggest problem** ... is that once I get the jQ to work it effects every visible node in the list/feed since im calling the function via a div id or a class. I understand why this is happening but what i can't figure out is how to **get the jQ to make an impact only on the node in which the button is being pressed.**

This is what i have so far within my node-template for a specific content-type:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">                                         
(function ($) {

 $('.up2').click(function () {
        $('.nummer_dark').text(parseInt($('.nummer_dark').text())+1,0).toFixed(2);
   $('.up2').toggle();


      });

       $('.up').one('click', function() {
        $('.flag-link-toggle').click();once();


      });


})(jQuery);

 </script>
```

This is just an example where I'm trying to increase the number within a span by pressing an object with the up2-class and toggle a flag by pressing an object with the up-class.

The first code works but the number is increased with decimals ( 2.453, 3.4123 etc) instead of just 1,2,3,4 as i planned. But the main problem is that these both codes are giving effect on every node in the list.. I know this is because every node in the list have the same node-template and thus the same classes but **i want to find a solution using the node-id in the jQ.**

Any leading answers would save my day!  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make use of the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) methods.  This will allow you to locate just the parent node containing the button that was just clicked so you can find and change just the child element of that node.  Here is some quick psuedo code showing how it would work.

```
$('.up2').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.node').find('.nummer_dark').text();
}
```

Comment: try adding a `console.log($(this).closest('.node'));` inside the click function to see if its at least finding the parent node.

Comment: can you also confirm that the `.node` class is actually on the parent node elements in your `View`? A better class may be something like `.views-row`.

Comment: Well, its hard to give exact code without knowing the structure of your view.  But the class that goes into the `.closest()` call needs to be a class from the first element that contains both the button and the element you want to act upon during button push.  I believe `.views-row` is a safe bet assuming you use the default classes in your view.  I use the same trick I posted here: http://nextawards.org/awardees/2012 for the expandable "Read More" divs.

Comment: And now it works for every node. Thank you sir, you have saved me hours and hours of work!